# Unable to get spyder to work with python3 (properly*)

Tags: updates, python, pip, spyder

As my attempts to migrate to python3
(See [Switching from python2 to python3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850254/switching-from-python2-to-python3) ) continue;

Trying to install spyder with pip3 i arrived at a functioning workspace (although with no nautilus access to it, only via terminal).
 Updating the system and then restarting rendered it (for some unknown reason) no longer accessible; typing *spyder* in terminal results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ImportError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 103, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 49, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 39, in check_qt
    import qtpy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
```

Then, after bringing my system to spyder-free state, tried to install spyder3 with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install spyder3
```

which resulted in a new spyder (version 2.*) that runs python 3.

The problem is updating it to version 3.*. 
pip does not recognize any 'spyder3' and so i tried

```
pip3 install -U spyder
```

resulting in, although updated, **another** spyder application on my computer; that is i can

```
which spyder3; which spyder
```

and get 2 different locations with spyder3 being v2.* and spyder being v3.*.

If only the "right" spyder would appear in nautilus - I could live with this oddity, but it opens up the "not updated spyder".

So to summarize things up:

- Option A gives me a non-working spyder (and no access via nautilus).
- Option B gives me 2 working spyder located in different places, 1 is version 2.* and accessible via nautilus, the other is version 3.* and inaccssible via nautilus.

What am i doing wrong?...

Comment: You didn't really do anything wrong. What you have described so far are two different installation methods that give expected results. Can you clarify what end result do you prefer? Do you prefer v3 to v2 of Spyder? What do you mean by "accessible via Nautilus"?

Comment: @edwinksl I would like to have v3 and it's important for me that it can be updated regulary with pip. When i say "accesible via nautilus" i mean there is no image anywhere to click on that will open spyder.

Answer (score 1):

When installing spyder with pip3; PyQt4 packages was needed:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4
```

Having installed that gave me the much wanted spyder IDE, working in version 3 and python3.5.

When launching spyder with terminal I get:

```
void DBusMenuExporterPrivate::addAction(QAction*, int): Already tracking action "Project explorer" under id 124
```

But a post in github (with a much relevant difficulty) reassured me: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3521

Comment: When you did `sudo apt-get install spyder3`, `python3-pyqt4` would have been installed as a dependency according to http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/spyder3 and http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python3-spyderlib, so I am not sure why you have to do `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4` again.

Comment: @edwinksl Yes you are right, but installing spyder with pip3 did not install pyqt4. I prefered this as i can then update spyder more regulary (Edited my post to indicate that I eventually installed it with pip3).