# Spyder3 not launching on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, python3, spyder

I am relatively new to the Linux environment and also have no experience in using python before.

I am trying to install Spyder3 on Xbuntu 16.04.
I installed using `pip3`.

```
pip3 install spyder3
```

But when I try to open it on terminal, it gives me Segmentation fault.

Any tip what I can do?

- XUbuntu - 16.04 (64bit)
- Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Please read [documentation](https://docs.xubuntu.org/1604/user/C/managing-applications.html) on managing software in Xubuntu. Note that spyder3 is [available in the **universe** repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=spyder&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all).

So why not remove Spyder installed by pip and start from using a packaged version?

Concerning issue at hand, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/851092/735629) to [Unable to get spyder to work with python3 (properly*)](https://askubuntu.com/q/851001/735629) might be of help.